# Data type cannot be converted in matlab or excel

Tags: database, excel, matlab, import, quotes

I recently copy and pasted some data from a database (USGS stream gauge data to be specific. I copy and pasted into excel, creating a column of my own for time.

When I import the data into matlab, only the column I made shows up.

```
obs = xlsread('ObservedMR.xlsx','jun30For');
```

I tried to convert the values in excel to numbers, but to no avail. In excel, the numbers are left justified (which I know means that they are not being registered as numbers), but there are no other characters visible.

When I create an empty matrix and try to copy and paste data in, I get an error reading that I cannot paste data that contains strings.

Using the following,

```
 p = readtable('ObservedMR.xlsx','Sheet','jun30For')
```

I get

```
p = 

x0       x0_31  
___    _________

  1    '0.31  ' 
  2    '0.31  ' 
  3    '0.31  ' 
  4    '0.31  ' 
  5    '0.31  ' 
  6    '0.31  '
```

I got error messages trying to use str2num (requires string or character input) and table2array.(types double and cell).

I was going to try to use

```
regexprep(p, ''' , '')
```

to replace the quotes, but I am getting messages about the single quotes being unclosed.

Does anyone know how I can use this data, by writing a code to edit out the quotes and spaces, import another way, convert it some way, etc?

Thank you!

Comment: you should be able to tell what format they are in when you select column right click and properties in excel.

Comment: It sounds like you have white space issues. In Excel try find and replace on the non-breaking space character. Otherwise, it could be that your regional settings expect a `,` as the decimal point but your sheet has `.`. Again, a find and replace in Excel is probably the easiest fix.

Comment: @GameOfThrows For some reason, excel doesn't allow me to view properties.  I am using windows 10, so that could be why I cannot see it.

Comment: @Dan I had tried the first option yesterday. I tried using the commas right now and that also did not work.

Answer (score 0):

you can specify the format of the columns in `readtable`.

```
p = readtable('ObservedMR.xlsx','Sheet','jun30For', 'Format', '%f%f')
```

will read the columns as floats. If it doesn't do the conversion correctly, try reading them as strings `%s` and then using `str2num` once you have them in Matlab.

Anyway I would suggest correcting your data in Excel. If you click on the cell and look at the formula bar you will probably see a quote ' at the left of the number which indicates the cell is stored as text. Convert it to number, save the Excel and done.

Comment: I tried to use the above line but I am getting the error Invalid parameter name: Format. I think it may have to do with the whatever the error is itself. I tried both with float and strings. In excel, no quote appears in the formula bar. I have tried converting the cells to numbers, but to no avail.

Comment: Just a stupid thing. Could it be that the decimal separator is a comma instead of a point? If you have configured Excel like this (some countries use comma), then using a point will be considered as text.